# translate using https://angular-translate.github.io/

Tags: angularjs

i am using https://angular-translate.github.io/ module for translation

my key array is

```
$scope.array = [
    "full_name",
    "email",
    "phone_no"
];
```

and my translation for that is

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
        full_name:'full name',
        email:'email',
        phone_no:'phone no'
});
```

and have code like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
  {{item | translate}}
</div>
```

but i can't get translation. can anyone help to do proper way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the preferred language in the configuration? If you don't do so, the `'en'` translations won't be applied.

```
.config(function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    /* ... */
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

[Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VqI9h8yzpVdgrFgvB95m)

Comment: Have you seen the plunkr demo? Is there any difference with your code?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate'])

  .config(function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
      full_name: 'Full name',
      email:     'Email address',
      phone_no:  'Phone number'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage(['en']);
  })

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = ['full_name','email','phone_no']; 
});
```

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: can you provide me a plunker @mikko viitala